# Call Twig truncate filter inside a controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to use twig truncate filter inside a controller. I do not use a Twig template because my controller only return a json object.

From the [Twig Text extension](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php) source, I saw that the filter function is `twig_truncate_filter`, so I tried to get the extension as a service and call the filter function it in my controller :

```
$something = "a long character string that need to be truncated";
$twigText = $this->get("twig.extension.text");
$twig = $this->get("twig");
$truncatedValue = $twigText->twig_truncate_filter($twig,$something)
```

It give me a Fatal error: `Call to undefined method Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text::twig_truncate_filter()`.

How can I use the filter feature directly in my controller ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably there is a shorter way, but the following worked for me:

```
$filters = $this->get('twig.extension.text')->getFilters();
$callable = $filters['truncate']->getCallable();

$truncated = $callable($this->get('twig'), $str));
```

For Twig Extensions > 1.3 you can use this

```
$filters = $this->get('twig.extension.text')->getFilters();
$key = array_search('truncate', array_map(function(TwigFilter $filter) { return $filter->getName(); }, $filters), true);
$callable = $filters[$key]->getCallable();
    
$truncated = $callable($this->get('twig'), $str));
```

Comment: `getFilters()` returns non-indexed array, at least in Twig Extensions version  1.3.0.

Comment: Please revise your answer, because as **TheForst** mentioned, `getFilters` returns an array with numerical keys

Answer (score 6):

If you look closely at the [Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/src/TextExtension.php#L36) file, you'll see that `twig_truncate_filter` is actually declared as a global function, not part of the *Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text* class.

That class merely acts as a wrapper for a Twig filter, *truncate*, to call that global *twig_truncate_filter* function.

You can simply call it directly in your controller:

```php
$truncatedValue = twig_truncate_filter($twig, $something);
```

Comment: Is this true with self-defined filters? I don't think so. Please consider generalising your answer.

Comment: Where in the question or my answer does it say anything about self-defined filters?

Comment: @duncan This is true with Twig's Intl filters which I am glad to say has promptly ended a couple of hours of unsuccessful attempts to localise dropdown text with a date in it. Thanks for the insight!